# Replace dismissed widget with new widget in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am getting an error with my current implementation of my Dismissable widget. It returns the 'Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissable widget' error. The error makes sense to me, but I am trying to reset the state of the widget. I can't figure out how to set the onDismissed property return a new card. I am using the Dismissable widget on a card. And I would like to be able to dismiss the card and automatically replace it with a new one. Is the dismissable widget even the appropriate route I should be taking? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to include your code (paired down to just what's necessary), it would most likely be much easier to see what's going on. In future questions, please include an example as it'll help us help you =).

That being said, it seems you might have a little bit of confusion about how to use the Dismissable widget. Basically, it will show its child and will handle the dismissal gesture, but you are responsible from removing it from the list (assuming this is in a list). From the [Dismissable documentation:](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html)

> If the Dismissible is a list item, it must have a key that
>   distinguishes it from the other items and its onDismissed callback
>   must remove the item from the list.

What that is saying is that if the Dismissable is in a list, you must externally manage the state of the list and the items within. I wouldn't be surprised if this is also true when the Dismissable isn't in a list.

Basically, you should be doing something in that callback to remove the Dismissable and its' child from your list. The most likely way for that to happen is that the Dismissable and the list it is contained in are built in a class inheriting State.

Say for example you have a list of items stored as a member variable of the State: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. If you dismiss 8, you should then be building from the list 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10. If you simply remove the 8th item from the list it won't quite work as dart isn't smart enough to compare list items - it will still see the list as being the same list. So you could either make a copy of the list without the 8 and set the member to that, or use a second variable (something like count) that gets incremented whenever there is a change so that flutter knows to rebuild the State.

Now, what you're doing is slightly more complicated than even that - you want to replace the item with something else. What I would then recommend doing is changing (or copying) the list form 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 -> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8*,9,10 within the OnDismissed callback, and calling setState appropriately, with the 8* being some sort of object which indicates that the list item has been dismissed.

When you build your list item, it should take into account the fact that 8 has been changed to 8* and build the new widgets appropriately.